# NextJS - Send user to a custom url and handle the response from a third party app

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am building an app that will send the customer to a URL which asks the user to open an app (url starts with zel:) and then the app will send a request to my server. I want to achieve the following journey:

1. The user clicks on the login button.
2. The user is asked to open an app and finish signing in.
3. The app uses a callback to send a message to my server, saying that the customer finished signing in.
4. I verify that the user has signed in, and then redirect them to a new path (example: /afterlogin)

I am not sure how to achieve that. Can you help me?

I have the following code:

```
// pages/login.js

import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Login() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const handleClick = () => {
        axios.get('https://api.runonflux.io/id/loginphrase').then(response => {
            if (response.data.status === 'success') {
                var loginPhrase = response.data.data;
                if (loginPhrase) {
                    router.push(`zel:?action=sign&message=${loginPhrase}&callback=${process.env.DOMAIN}api/validateSignature`);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the login page where the user will click on the login button, a request to an API will be made to obtain a phrase, and then the user will be redirected to open an app and sign the message.

```
// pages/api/validateSignature.js

export default function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'GET') {

    }
    var url = "https://api.runonflux.io/id/verifylogin";
    var axios = require('axios');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "loginPhrase": req.body.message,
        "signature": req.body.signature,
        "zelid": req.body.address
    });
    var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: data
    };
    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

This will handle the app callback.

I also made a video showing the flow - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn4j5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is implementing MongoDB to help me with this.

I am redirecting the user to a waiting page, which checks MongoDB every 3 seconds to see if the customer finished signing in:

```
// pages/waiting/[loginPhrase.js]
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const WaitingPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { loginPhrase } = router.query
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkApi = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/checkMessage', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ "loginPhrase": loginPhrase }),
                });
                const json = await response.json();
                console.log(json.data[0]);
                if (json.data[0] !== undefined) {
                    const responseVerify = await fetch('https://api.runonflux.io/id/verifylogin', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({ "address": json.data[0].address, "message": json.data[0].message, "signature": json.data[0].signature }),
                    });
                    const respJson = await responseVerify.json();
                    console.log(respJson);
                    if (respJson.status === 'success' && respJson.data.message == 'Successfully logged in') {
                        router.push(`/success`);
                    }
                }
            } catch (err) {
                setLoading(false);
                console.error(err);
            }
        };

        const intervalId = setInterval(checkApi, 3000);
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, []);


    return (
        <div>
            {loading ? (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            ) : data ? (
                <p>Data received: {JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
            ) : (
                <p>No data received</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default WaitingPage;
```

And I implemented two api calls - one for the app callback, which will write data to MongoDB:

```
// pages/api/signedMessage.js
import clientPromise from "../../lib/mongodb";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("zel_login");
    if (req.method === "POST") {
        if (!req.body.address || !req.body.message || !req.body.signature) {
            return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: "Bad Request" })
        }
        let messageObject = {
            createdAt: new Date(new Date().toISOString()),
            address: req.body.address,
            message: req.body.message,
            signature: req.body.signature
        }
        let newMessage = await db.collection("signed_messages").insertOne(messageObject);
        res.json(newMessage);
    }
}
```

And one that will try to find the loginPhrase and then verify it with an additional API call:

```
// pages/api/checkMessage.js
import clientPromise from "../../lib/mongodb";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("zel_login");
    if (req.method === "POST") {
        const message = await db.collection("signed_messages").find({ "message": req.body.loginPhrase }).toArray();
        res.json({ status: 200, data: message });
    }
}
```